# Android tutorial import failure

Tags: android, import

Hey I am really new in android and I tried [this tutorial](http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537). I followed the steps but the class viewpageradapter I can't import

```
$ import com.jakewharton.android.viewpagerindicator.TitleProvider;
```

Like the tutorial mentioned I did

> " Properties|Android”, then clicking “Add…” in the Library section and selecting the ViewPagerIndicator library. "

But the import still can't be resolved. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You can start by explaining what "i can't import" and "can't be resolved" mean. Are you getting error messages? If so, what are they **exactly**? Please remember when posting that we can't see your screen (or your code) from here. All we have to go on to try and help you is what you write in your question. If it's "not working", you need to explain in what way. If you "get an error", you need to tell us what that error is exactly (with any error message). We can help you much more easily (and more quickly) if you provide the details of the problem. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of i think you have tried to download the sample code given in his website for the information. if that is not the case please do. then the `com.jakewharton` is specifically for his program. it is like check for the component in the `com.jakewharton.android.viewpagerindicator` which i think is not the same in your case. so please check that and change appropirately.

Answer (score 0):

change

> com.jakewharton.android.viewpagerindicator

to

> com.viewpagerindicator.TitleProvider

Answer (score 0):

Your git directory needs to be in your workbench folder I guess. Apparently eclipse doesn’t like it if it’s not.

Comment: answers should be based on knowledge, not on guessing